# Python -Selenium - Bluemix - Running selenium on Bluemix

Tags: python, selenium, ibm-cloud

I have a scraping script which uses selenium.

Is there any way to deploy it under IBM Bluemix?

P.S. as i see the main problem is launching webdriver browser in a web application.